# Create local copy of Amazon RDS Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

How do I mysqldump the database on my AWS RDS instance to a .sql file for local use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy:

```
mysqldump -H <RDS_URL> -u <user> -p<password> <db> > myfile.sql
```

As long as you add the `-H` with proper user / password credentials, you'll have no problem.

Comment: Just a quick note for future viewers: you may need to use `-h` (lowercase) instead. The capitalized flag didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a client like MySQL Work Bench to open it remotely and export it to .sql anytime you feel like.

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/