# Local Download of Amazon RDS database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I am looking to create a local version of my companies database from Amazon's RDS service.  Luckily, I was able to find a possible answer to my question here:

[Create local copy of Amazon RDS Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133979/create-local-copy-of-amazon-rds-database)

but the asnwer on that link conflicts with the answer to a very similar question here:

[Local replica of RDS database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553371/local-replica-of-rds-database)

Unfortunately, since I am but a new user on this site and stackoverflow has a rewards system, I cannot comment on the answer for further follow up because of my reputation.  Here is the line of code that the link says will copy my database on Amazon RDS to a local location

```
   mysqldump -H <RDS_URL> -u <user> -p<password> <db> > myfile.sql
```

Can some one please answers these questions regarding the answer given to the first link or let me know if it is the second link that is correct?

Will this work?  If not, is there another way of doing it?  If I am a user under a company account, will this still work for me?  If not, how can I change this so that I can give the command a account, user name, and password?

Comment: I think the 2nd question is about something else (repliction, though it's not totally clear). The command in the question (mysqldump) should be OK get a copy of the database, but you need to make sure that the IP address where you run this command from is added to you RDS security group for the given DB instance.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, I think I just ran into this problem, can you tell me how to do that. I have never used RDS before and my boss kinda just threw me into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second answer is what you're looking for.

```
mysqldump -h <RDS_URL> -u <user> -p<password> <db> > myfile.sql
```

will save a dump of your database on your local machine.

The other answer you linked regards the MASTER/SLAVE replication, in which two database servers work in tandem to achieve some load balancing, and keep themselves synchronized in near real time. Not your case.

**Edit:**

Amazon Console -> RDS -> pick instance -> properties

[image]

It's where it says endpoint.

**Edit 2:** -h parameter must be lowercase. My bad.

Comment: So tge <RDS_URL> is just the sign in site for Amazon RDS?  It asks for a account, username, and password, but in this command I only give it a username and password.  Or would the administrator of the account have to do this command?

Comment: Nope. Is the IP or hostname of your RDS instance, which you must find in your amazon console dashboard. Just click the instance and display its properties to find out.

Comment: Does there need to be a space between -p and the password?

Comment: No, there is no space.  It's `-pYOURPASSWORD`.

Comment: I did not see a an IP label or hostname/  What am I looking for in the instance under properties

Comment: I am getting an error "mysqldump: unknown option '-H'"

Comment: I am getting "mysqldump: Got Error: 2003: Can't connet to MYSQL server in '...' (111) when trying to connect".  I looked up I need to somehow give permission of my IP addess but I am not sure if thats right or how to do that.

Comment: You must give permission to your IP in your Amazon dashboard -> RDS -> Security Groups